# Vim status line not working

Tags: macos, vim, statusline

I'm on OS X and I've installed Vim using Homebrew via

```
brew install vim
```

I noticed that whenever I use Vim, there is no status line appearing at the bottom. I thought I could fix it by always displaying the status line by adding the following to vimrc:

```
:set laststatus=2
```

This shows me the status line but it's just an empty line above the ruler. It looks like this:
[image]

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I want to use Vim for Haskell. I've installed [haskell-vim-proto](https://github.com/sdiehl/haskell-vim-proto/tree/master/vim). I'm using the included included [vimrc](https://github.com/sdiehl/haskell-vim-proto/blob/master/vimrc) which should result in showing things like syntax errors in the status line. When I edit Haskell files (with the [vimrc](https://github.com/sdiehl/haskell-vim-proto/blob/master/vimrc)), there is no status bar in my Vim. Adding `set laststatus=2` to the vimrc results in a blank status line showing.

When I'm following tutorials that install Vim through HomeBrew (as I did), opening any time of file with Vim shows the status line at the bottom containing things like this:

I'm literally following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJV7m-NGwDg&list=PLiq_R1OaB2FKZxNFf16uhu5gfi3YufNEU) tutorial. When he opens .bash_profile with Vim, it looks like this:
[image]
When I do the exact same thing, it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The guy who made that tutorial made a very big and very common mistake: he is using a heavily customized Vim instead of vanilla Vim. This **rather obviously** gives new users wrong expectations.

Basically, everything you see in that first screenshot:

- colorful pseudo-tabline
- colorful statusline
- colorscheme
- relative line numbers

is either provided by one or more plugins that the author failed to mention or by a built-in option that he also failed to mention.

If you absolutely *need* an "always-on" statusline, follow @dNitro's suggestion.

If you absolutely *want* the exact same setup as the author (which is not a very good idea in and of itself), I'd suggest you contact him directly. People should take full responsibility of the crap they put online.

Comment: That could be the problem. But what should I do then, to get haskell-vim-proto working? Because I'm installing as instructed and my status bar is still blank, even with the vimrc from haskell-vim-proto.

Comment: First, you *shouldn't* use a "distribution" like that haskell-vim-proto thing. Two, if you absolutely insist on using that crap, [use its issue tracker](https://github.com/sdiehl/haskell-vim-proto/issues).

Answer (score 7):

Status line by default is just like that gray line and will always remains there as long as you `set laststatus=2`.

What you are missing is formatting this line to show the items you want it to show you. you can do it manually yourself. just add the following to `.vimrc` and see what happens:

```
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w%=\ [%Y]\ [%{&ff}]\ [%04l,%04v]\ [%p%%]\ [%L]
```

to decipher see: `:help statusline` and add your desired items.

Or use a plugin: [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) and [lightline.vim](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) are two popular one.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm literally following a tutorial. The guy in the tutorial installs Vim through brew, exactly as I did. When he uses Vim to edit any file, the status line shows things like the mode he's in, file type, character encoding, etc.
I want to use vim for Haskell. I've installed haskell-vim-proto and I'm using his vimrc to which contains configuration for advanced features. When I use that vimrc, there is no status line at all, even though it should show many things. When I add `set laststatus=2` to that file, the status line is just blank.

Comment: I think they used fully featured setup script: [haskell-vim-now](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now) and in this repository's .vimrc it icludes [Plug 'bling/vim-airline'](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now/blob/d6fd8d84e2450add3bd44e8b3d873ba46b143634/.vimrc#L101), means they use [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plugin.

Comment: Yes, I know. But sadly, I can't get haskell-vim-now to install... The installation fails with this error:
`curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "par--patch"
Download failed: http://sysmic.org/dl/par/par_1.52-i18n.4.patch
*** Installer requires 'par'. Please install and try again.
*** Aborting...`

Comment: 1. `cd ~/Desktop`, 2. `git clone https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now.git`, 3. `cd haskell-vim-now`, 4.`install.sh --repo ~/Desktop/haskell-vim-now`

Comment: How would that solve the error I get? I just get the exact same error by doing that:
`==> Downloading http://sysmic.org/dl/par/par_1.52-i18n.4.patch

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "par--patch"
Download failed: http://sysmic.org/dl/par/par_1.52-i18n.4.patch
*** Installer requires 'par'. Please install and try again.
*** Aborting...`

Comment: Installer requires 'par': Do `brew up` and `brew install par`, then try again.

Comment: I get a similar error now:
`--- Installing system packages [par] using [BREW]...
--- Installing with homebrew...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
 from`
`*** Installer requires 'par'. Please install and try again.
*** Aborting...`

Comment: I am suspicious that you are not added `/usr/local/bin` to $PATH. so do: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and try again. If same error, take @romainl suggestion and report issue to its maintainers.